# Very strange iPhone app crash problem with tabbar based app

Tags: iphone, crash, background, uitabbar

I know the title sounds a bit awkward but let me explain my problem.

I have a tab bar based iPhone app which works perfectly so far. I can switch through the tabs and every tab loads a view controller.

But here is how it crashes. After I used the app and working with a bunch of other apps I switch back to my app (for example after one hour). The app shows the screen where I left it. Now when I try to change the tab, it crashes immediately.

The problem is that I can't reproduce this crash in the simulator or in the debug mode. I tried to open it, then close it, then reopen it but then everything works. Only after a certain amount of time the crash can be reproduced. But I don't have any logs.

Maybe anyone had the same the problem and knows what to do here?

Comment: Connect your iPhone to xcode windows organizer to analyze crash logs.

Comment: crashing occurs on device or simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be related to low memory (i.e., you have a bug that only shows up during low memory)?  Have you tried "Simulate Memory Warning" in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device with system using iPhone utility and found the reason for crash.  It may be memory problem only.